# running imported nsis code from within a compiled nsis executable

Tags: java, plugins, windows-installer, installation, nsis

Is it possible to import nsis code and run it from within a compiled nsis executable?

Suppose I have a nsis script `fubar.nsi` and compile it to `fubar.exe`. For strange reasons*, I also have some additional nsis statements that I want to read in and execute when fubar.exe is run - I am not sure what they will be until then.

Does a plugin or method to do this exist? Or is it simply not possible/advisable?

*the reason is I have several small software updates and I would rather run the statements sequentially together, prompting `1` Windows UAC request, than execute `x` separate .exe files instead and generate `x` requests.

**Edit:** I think a better approach might be to use the `UAC` plugin for the separate `.exe` files combined with setting

```
SilentInstall silent
AutoCloseWindow true
ShowInstDetails hide
```

in the individual updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, using the `UAC plugin` for the separate `.exe` files combined with setting

```
SilentInstall silent
AutoCloseWindow true
ShowInstDetails hide
```

in the individual updates worked for me to produce only one initial UAC request. I am quite happy with this. : )